# How to change tracking ID in a Google Analytics Property

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am tracking user behaviours from my app using Google analytics with a specific Tracking-ID since years.
Now I realised, that no data is tracked anymore, but I didn't change anything !

After analysis I can see that my Tracking-ID, that I am using from my App is not matching to any Tracking ID's of mit Google Analytics Properties. 
From the It is not possible to change the Tracking ID or I don't know.

How to change the tracking ID or how to create a Property with a specific Tracking ID ? I would like not to loose all my tracking data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of February 4th 2020, Google Analytics properties was permanently deleted. See here for more details: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The Tracking ID is generated automatically once you create a property and you can't change it or create a specific ID of your choice. You may read more here https://analyticshelp.io/blog/google-analytics-property-tracking-id/

If the Tracking ID of your property and App are not matching, it means that either there was a change in the App or you are looking at the wrong property from Google Analytics.